# Average irreducible character of $O(N)$

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let $O(N)$ be the group of $N\times N$ real orthogonal matrices, and let $\chi_R(g)=\sum_i M^{(R)}_{ii}(g)$ denote the character of $g\in O(N)$ in the irreducible representation $R$, i.e. the trace of the matrix that represents it.

Orthogonality of matrix elements $\int M^{(R)}_{ik}(g)M^{(S)}_{lj}(g^{-1}) dg=\frac{1}{D_R}\delta_{RS}\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl},$ where $D_R$ is the dimension of $R$, implies the convolution equation
$\int \chi_R(Ag)\chi_S(Bg^{-1}) dg=\delta_{RS}\frac{\chi_R(AB)}{D_R}$.

The average value of $\chi_R(Ag)$ can be written as $\int \chi_R(Ag)\chi_0(Bg^{-1}) dg$, where $\chi_0(g)=1$ is the character of the trivial representation.

I believe all of the above to be true. Yet, it is leading me to a confusion, because it means that the average value of $\chi_R(Ag)$ equals $\delta_{R0}$.

The problem is that this quantity does not depend on $A$, and this cannot be true. Characters are a basis for class functions, so this would mean that the average value of any class function of $Ag$ would be independent of $A$, which seems too strong. What about $({\rm Tr}(Ag))^2$, for instance?

What is the mistake?

In the end I am interested in class functions. Suppose a class function $F(g)$ for which I know the character expansion, $F(g)=\sum_R c_R\chi_R(g)$. Does this equation still hold if $g \notin O(N)$? I guess this would work for $GL(N,\mathbb{C})$, by some denseness argument, but it might not work for $O(N)$...

Comment: What is $A$ ? If $A$ is an element of $G$ then the average value of $f(A.)$ doesn't depend on $A$ because your measure is left invariant. $G$ is compact so it is also right invariant. If $f$ is a class function then $f(A.)$ doesn't have to be one.

Comment: @reuns $A$ is not an element of the group

Comment: What is $A$. In $\chi_R(Ag)$ you need $Ag\in G$.

Comment: I was assuming that I could just take $\chi_R(g)$ as a polynomial in the eigenvalues of $g$ and compute it at the eigenvalues of $Ag$, even if $Ag\notin O(N)$. I will include this point in the question

Comment: No. Perhaps you are trying to say $tr(A  M^R(g))$ with $A\in M_N(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: @reuns That is not what I mean. $g$ and $A$ are $N\times N$, while $M^R(g)$ is of dimension $D_R$.

Comment: Then maybe you want $R$ to be the restriction to $O(N)$ of a representation of $M_N(\Bbb{R})$, in which case $tr(M^R(Ag))$ is well-defined for $A\in M_N(\Bbb{R}),g\in O(N)$.